# OnSelect issue in Multiselect drop-down

Tags: reactjs

I am new in React Js for Mulitiselect dropdown i have used "npm install react-multi-select-component" plugin but my onSelect is not Working.

```
  <Multiselect

    showCheckbox={true}

    options={this.state.options} // Options to display in the dropdown

     selectedValues={this.state.selectedOption} // Preselected value to persist in dropdown

     onSelect={alert("hi")} // Function will trigger on select event

     onRemove={this.onRemove} // Function will trigger on remove event

     displayValue="name" // Property name to display in the dropdown options
/>;
```

Comment: try `onSelect={() => alert("hi")}`

Answer (score 0):

After going through the documentation of your package `react-multi-select-component`, to trigger change events you have to use `onChange` prop instead of `onSelect`. You can do it like this.

```
selectHandler = () => {
 console.log("event triggered")
}

<Multiselect
  showCheckbox={true}
  options={this.state.options} 
  selectedValues={this.state.selectedOption} 
  onChange={() => this.selectHandler()}
  onRemove={this.onRemove}
  displayValue="name" 
/>;
```

I think you have mistakenly referred the documentation of the package `multiselect-react-dropdown`, which has the props you have used and some of them are not available in `react-multi-select-component`. You can refer the documentation of your component [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-multi-select-component).

Answer (score 0):

**I also had problems using react-multi-select-component I am doing well with react-picky I invite you to use it**

```
import Picky from "react-picky";
import "react-picky/dist/picky.css";


 <Picky
  value={proyecto}
  options={DataProyectoApi}
  onChange={this.onChangeProyecto}
  open={false}
  valueKey="id_proyecto"
  labelKey="nombre"
  multiple={false}
  includeSelectAll={false}
  includeFilter={true}
  dropdownHeight={200}
  placeholder={"No hay datos seleccionados"}
  allSelectedPlaceholder={"seleccionaste todo"}
  manySelectedPlaceholder={"tienes %s seleccionados"}
  className="text-dark form-group-sm"
/>
```